# Post request returning homepage for subset of users

Tags: jquery, .post

I've been using the same code for many years without issue and recently its not behaving as expected.

```
  $.post('/stripe/ajax/initialize_total_cost.php', {}, function (result) {
                 
                }, 'json').error(function (xhr) {
                    handleUserRegistrationError(data, xhr.responseText);

                });
```

When the above code is run, for a small subset of users, the xhr.responseText is the HTML from my homepage.  I've spoken to a few of them and they're using the same setup as I am (Chrome on a Mac).  In addition, I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it (doubtful but it's another piece), but the users affected seem to just be European customers.

To start my debugging process, I'm just hoping to understand if there are conditions in which a post request would return the HTML from my homepage.

Comment: That sounds like a PHP issue and not a POST issue. HTTP POST just sends the data. If the text you are getting back in the response is HTML, that is being generated by your PHP script.

Comment: That makes sense. But I'm not seeing from my script how the homepage is what's being returned.  Meeting with one of the affected users tomorrow which will hopefully shed some light!

Comment: Perhaps PHP is throwing an Error and instead of the error page, the homepage is being sent back. No way to know from the post you have created.

Comment: This may be a bit of a narrowly beneficial answer but I'll post it anyway.  What was happening is that the user was embedding my URL as an External Tool within an LMS context and it was the LMS' logic which was causing the issue.  Pasting the URL directly in the browser fixed the issue.